# Oracle 10g Client for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, oracle-10g

I downloaded the Oracle 10g Client Release 2 from [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), the one that says it is compatible with Vista, Windows Server, and Windows 7.

However, when I run the installer, it says that the platform is incorrect. I downloaded the 32-bit release and I am running 32-bit Windows 7.

Does anyone know where I can download the 32-bit Windows 7 Oracle 10g client?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure you downloaded the correct package, also See this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206440/will-windows-7-support-the-oracle-10g-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 10g R2 Client is not officially certified for Windows 7 - you need Oracle 11g R2 client. I'm not sure which version you've downloaded - the link in your question points to Oracle 11g R2 client.

Comment: Note that the 11g R2 client is able to access 10g databases and earlier with no problems.

Comment: 9i - 11g @Michael

Answer (score -1):

You should check your Windows version select *Run* -> *winver* -> *OK*). You should download the Oracle client that is compatible not just with your Windows 7 but also with your Windows version.